# GNU scientific library linking

Tags: installation, makefile

My GNU scientific library (http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) installed in the path: /home/myname/gsl-1.6
My mlRho 1.7-stat prog (http://guanine.evolbio.mpg.de/mlRho/mlRho_1.7.tgz) which uses GNU scientific library-installed in:`/home/myname/MlRho_1.7`

my operating system: Fedora 16

original make file in mlRho

```
cd  /home/myname/MlRho_1.7/

vim make

CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -O3 -Wall -Wshadow -pedantic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVER32 \
    -I/opt/local/include/ -L/opt/local/lib/
```

I have changed path in mlRho

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -O3 -Wall -Wshadow -pedantic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVER32 \
    -I/home/myname/gsl-1.6 -L/home/myname/gsl-1.6
```

after making changes, I tried running make, it gives error

```
make
gcc -O3 -Wall -Wshadow -pedantic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVER32 -I/home/myname/gsl-1.6/include/ -L/home/myname/gsl-1.6/lib/     -c -o mlRho.o mlRho.c
In file included from mlRho.c:16:0:
mlComp.h:7:30: fatal error: gsl/gsl_sf_gamma.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mlRho.o] Error 1
```

when i do make test- it gives me error below

```
make test

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/myname/MlRho_1.7/TestMlPi'
gcc -O3 -Wall -Wshadow -pedantic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVER32 -I/opt/local/include/ -L/opt/local/lib/   -c -o testMlPi.o testMlPi.c
testMlPi.c: In function ‘main’:
testMlPi.c:62:67: warning: variable ‘sderr’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
testMlPi.c:62:60: warning: variable ‘sdhet’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
gcc -O3 -Wall -Wshadow -pedantic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVER32 -I/opt/local/include/ -L/opt/local/lib/   -c -o interface.o interface.c
gcc -O3 -Wall -Wshadow -pedantic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVER32 -I/opt/local/include/ -L/opt/local/lib/   -c -o eprintf.o eprintf.c
gcc -O3 -Wall -Wshadow -pedantic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVER32 -I/opt/local/include/ -L/opt/local/lib/   -c -o ranNum.o ranNum.c
gcc -O3 -Wall -Wshadow -pedantic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVER32 -I/opt/local/include/ -L/opt/local/lib/ -o testMlPi testMlPi.o interface.o eprintf.o ranNum.o -lm 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/myname/MlRho_1.7/TestMlPi'
Output from testMlPi:
pi:             5.00e-05             epsilon:             4.90e-04             -log(L): 1.40e+05
Output from mlRho:
make: ./mlRho: Command not found
make: *** [testPi] Error 127
Output from mlRho:
make: ./mlRho: Command not found
make: *** [testPi] Error 127
```

It somehow GNU library not linking to mlRho programme. How to fix it?

Comment: Most likely your problem is with new `CFLAGS`, try changing `-I/home/myname/gsl-1.6 -L/home/myname/gsl-1.6` to `-I/home/myname/gsl-1.6/include -L/home/myname/gsl-1.6/lib`

Comment: it tried changing: -I/home/myname/gsl-1.6/include -L/home/myname/gsl-1.6/lib. still gives error:mlComp.h:7:30: fatal error: gsl/gsl_sf_gamma.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mlRho.o] Error 1

Comment: What does `find /home/myname/gsl-1.6 -name gsl_sf_gamma.h -type f` return?

Comment: find: `/home/myname/gsl-1.6': No such file or directory

Comment: Do you have required library installed in /home/myname/gsl-1.6 ? Looks like you don't have the libraries. Which is exact path where gsl is installed?

Comment: When running the `find` command you need to use the _proper_ path, that is, no "myname" stuff, but your actual username on the system. Then you can see where the needed `.h` files are located. If you're unlucky, you're missing the headers and need to install the development package to get them.